# Plotting Ellipsoids with large weight matrix

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'm running into some problems plotting 2D `Ellipsoid`s with non-diagonal weight matrices -- they are not centered where they are supposed to be. I'm not sure exactly what the problem is, it only seems to happen when the numbers are $\gg1$. The ellipse can even change positions if you change the plot range. The same thing happens with both `Epilog` and `Show`.

I am using version 10.0.2.0. Thanks for any help or workarounds. I am trying to plot ellipses corresponding to confidence regions on top of density plots, so the scales of the axes matter to me.

```
Row[
    Plot[x, {x, -500, 500}, 
        Epilog -> {Opacity[0], EdgeForm[Thick], 
            Ellipsoid[{0, 0}, 
                RotationMatrix[#].{{40000, 0}, {0, 20000}}.RotationMatrix[-#]]}, 
        AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 300
    ] & /@ {0, 10^-8, π/4}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second argument of Ellipse seems to need to be a vector (and not a matrix). In any case, try rotating the object. You'll also want to change the position ({0,0} below) to get it centered where you want. Something like:

```
Row[Plot[x, {x, -500, 500}, 
    Epilog -> {Opacity[0], EdgeForm[Thick], 
      Rotate[Ellipsoid[{0, 0}, {400, 200}], #]}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
    ImageSize -> 300] & /@ {0, \[Pi]/4}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, good fix. "The second argument of Ellipse seems to need to be a vector" -- the docs are clear it can be a matrix, I guess you mean it needs to be a vector to plot properly. They must have different plotting code for each case, and they also check to see if the matrix is diagonal or not.

Comment: I think there is may be some kind of bug. Consider `Plot[x, {x, -500, 500}, 
 Epilog -> {Rotate[
    Ellipsoid[{0, 0}, {{4000, 0}, {0, 2000}}], \[Pi]/4]}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1]` When I plot this, and move the cursor up and down, the position of the ellipse seems to jump around.

Comment: I have noticed weird stuff like this too! I was just not sure how to explain how to reproduce it, or if it was just another of the many small GUI problems with Mathematica in linux.

Comment: To make your answer more general (in most practical cases the rotation matrix would not be explicitly there), something like `makeEllipse[p_, mat_] := 
 Module[{d, v}, {d, v} = Eigensystem[mat]; 
  Rotate[Ellipsoid[p, Sqrt@d], ArcTan @@ (First@v)]]` would be good. Thanks again, I will accept.